# create a histogram using jooq

Tags: java, sql, histogram, jooq

I want to create a histogram of the values in a single column of a table, and I already know all the possible values for that col

so, in pseudo-sql, I want to do something like this:

```
select
count(my_col where my_col == "val_1") as "count_for_val_1",
count(my_col where my_col == "val_2") as "count_for_val_2",
etc
```

one caveat is that I want to use this style of query building in joog, as it makes conditional construction easier:

```
SelectQuery query = context.selectQuery();
query.addSelect(...)
query.addFrom(...)
etc
```

update: ok this seems to work:

```
SelectQuery query = context.selectQuery();
query.addSelect(my_table.my_col.decode("val_1", "any string here?").count().as("count_for_val_1"));
query.addSelect(my_table.my_col.decode("val_2", "any string here?").count().as("count_for_val_2"));
etc
```

now, is best way to do this in JOOQ? there are so many...

Comment: You may want to use the below answer field to provide your own answer for your question. That way, it will become immediately clear what the answer is for future visitors.

Comment: +1 to Lukas Elders comment. It would make this more readable if you put the answer in a self posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jOOQ's [`filterWhere()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/AggregateFilterStep.html#filterWhere-org.jooq.Condition...-) function, which can be used with all aggregate functions. I.e.

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
       count().filterWhere(MY_COL.eq("val_1")).as("count_for_val_1"),
       count().filterWhere(MY_COL.eq("val_2")).as("count_for_val_2"),
       ...
   )
   .from(...)
```

The SQL standard specifies the `AGGREGATE(...) FILTER (WHERE ...)` syntax, which is natively supported in PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE my_col = 'val_1') AS "count_for_val_1",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE my_col = 'val_2') AS "count_for_val_2",
  ...
FROM ...
```

In all other databases, jOOQ will generate the following instead

```sql
SELECT
  count(CASE WHEN my_col = 'val_1' THEN 1 END) AS "count_for_val_1",
  count(CASE WHEN my_col = 'val_2' THEN 1 END) AS "count_for_val_2",
  ...
FROM ...
```